# PHP Login page is blank instead of echoing results

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a login page to work with PHP and Mysql. I've combed through my code, and don't know where I'm going wrong.

First I have a "login.php" page. Here's (what I believe) is the important code on that page:

```
<form id="login" action="redirect.php" method="post"> <!--This is the form for logging in.-->    
<fieldset id="inputs">
        <input type="hidden" name="ac" value="log"> <!--This value is a "random" value to post so that an if statement will be entered in select.php-->
        <input id="username" name="username" type="text" placeholder="Username" autofocus required>   
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset id="actions">
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">    
    </fieldset>
```

From there you'll see that when submit is pressed it goes to "redirect.php" which has the following code:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

function SignIn()
{
session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page
if(!empty($username))   //check to see if the username is empty or not from login.php
{
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *  FROM employees where username = ".$username." AND password = ".$password) or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query) or die(mysql_error());
    if(!empty($row['username']) AND !empty($row['password']))
    {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];
        echo "SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN!";

    }
    else
    {
        echo "YOU ENTERED WRONG ID OR PASSWORD...";
    }
}
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}

?>
```

You'll notice the config.php page is included... Here's the code for that (with my dbusername and dbpassword changed:

```
<?php
/* Database credentials. */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'myusername');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
define('DB_NAME', 'ropepart_techportal');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$con = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($con === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
?>
```

When I run through all of this on my webpage, I am greeted with a blank white page on the redirect.php. This is the case no matter what username/password combo I put in the login.php page. Whether or not the user actually exists in the database or not. I would expect to get at least a sentence at the top of the page that either says "SUCCESSFULLY LOGGED IN!" or "YOU ENTERED WRONG ID OR PASSWORD." Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Why do people always code with massive SQL Injection vulnerabilities in their code?  `$_POST['password'] = '" OR 1=1 ';` AND I don't even need limit 1 for this one.  ie `SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "admin" AND password="" OR 1=1`

Comment: Always code with error_reporting(E_ALL), so that you will come to know what's going wrong

Comment: Put the following lines $username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password']; under signin function .

Comment: Another thing is you should encrypt `password_hash()` and you should never look up by the password,  if you pulled the PW from the DB and then compared it to the entered one it would prevent some errors that would allow someone to bypass the login. Also the DB in not case sensitive by default, you could set the field collation to UFF8_BIN to make ti case sensitive (this reduces the time it takes to brute force it, it reduces the complexity), but as I said you shouldn't look up by the password instead you should use `password_verify` to check it after pulling it from the DB by username/email

Answer (score 1):

You're not sending value for `submit` in post body.

Try adding :

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Log in">
```

Since you've checked `isset($_POST['submit'])` which since you're not sending evaluates to false , and `SignIn()` is never called

Answer (score 1):

I agree with our friend here, you set id for input, but you need set name to be send during the request, but I strong recomend u change two things in your code

add this attr to input submit -> `name="submit"`

Instead of this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    SignIn();
}
```

Use this

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    SignIn();
}
```

And don't do this on start of the code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Because when u try to access an array that is not defined the php can outputs an error, and for some security reasons this isn't recommend, so before set the variables, check it, like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username']) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
}
```

Comment: This is great! At least I'm getting an error instead of a blank page. I'm getting a Parse Error on this line:

if (isset($_POST['username']) $username = $_POST['username'];

Saying that $username was unexpected...I'm making progress but not there yet!

Comment: I think u should use like `if (isset($_POST['username']) {$username = $_POST['username'];}`

Answer (score 0):

Your intimidate problem is there is no scope resolution on your variables

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

function SignIn(){
  //$username  does not exist in this scope
```

Instead

```
function SignIn($username, $passwrd){
    ....
}

SignIn($username, $passwrd);
```

That said their is a bunch of other "stuff" that I would fix, give me a few minutes and I will post something on it.  Now if you had error reporting on you would see something like this

```
   Warning: undefined variable $username
```

Here you go (untested but it should be close)

```
<?php
//turn on error reporting for development
//note even this may not catch syntax errors if they happen in this file
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

require_once 'config.php';  //should be require once for a config

session_start();   //starting the session for user profile page

$dashboard = 'http://localhost/dashboard'; //some location to send a user after login

if(!empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    //user is already logged in
    header('Location: '.$dashboard);
}

//array for error tracking
$errors = [];


//if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
//by checking the below outside of this we are assuming post
// has already happend, so there is no need to check this
//it was similar in your original code.
//if post isn't set then username and password will be FALSE
//and it will be caught by the error checking for those anyway

$username = isset($_POST['username']) $_POST['username'] : false; //check if isset if not set a default
if(!$username) $errors[] = 'Please enter a username';

$password = isset($_POST['password']) $_POST['password'] : false;
if(!$password) $errors[] = 'Please enter a password';

if(count($errors)){
    //return to the page with error messages
    //I have no idea how you build the page or how it relates to this
    //so I cant hellp you there
    die(implode('<br>', $errors));
}else{
    //use single quotes for SQL, which prevents accidentally putting a variable in it.
    // '$password' is literally $password, but "$password" is the value of it
    //look up only what you need (password)
    //don't look up by the password, DB is case insensitive and 
    //and is not cryptologicalally secure way to compare hashes.
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, 'SELECT password FROM employees where username = ?');
    //I don't use mysqli (for like 4 years, and I never used the procedural style)
    //so I had to look this up, if it's not right sorry ;-/, this is so much harder then PDO
   /* bind parameters for markers */
   mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $user);

    /* execute query */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    /* bind result variables */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $hash);

    //not sure this will work, sorry
    //in the example it showed storing the results, 
    //so not sure if you have to do that.
    $num_rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);

    //check that one and only one row is returned
    if(!$num_rows){
        //User not found, again I have no idea how to display this for you
       die('Username was incorrect, please try again.');
    }else if($num_rows > 1){
       //should never happen with unique usernames
       // again I have no idea how to display this for you
       //this can prevent some errors from allowing logins
        //this is an error message you may not want to show in production code
       die('Returned more then one user account.');
    }

    /* fetch value */
    //because we did mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $hash)
    //which is bind $hash to column 1, this populates that
    //variable with the data from the first row
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);


    //bool password_verify ( string $password , string $hash )
    //Aug1 $password is plaintext, Arg2 $hash is from the DB
    if(password_verfy($password, $hash)){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username']; 
        //you had password here in your original code (another bug?)
        //$_SESSION['username'] = $row['password'];
        //user is already logged in
        header('Location: '.$dashboard);     
    }else{
        //Incorrect password, again I have no idea how to display this for you
       die('Your password was incorrect, please try again.'); 
    }   
}
```

I ditched the function call, as you mentioned in the comments.

> I decided to get rid of my SignIn() function entirely, as it seems to not be needed in this case

You can read about prepared statements here

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

As I mentioned in the code, I haven't used mysqli much in the last 4 years, and even then I never used the procedural style.  I quit doing the procedural style when I switched from mysql to mysqli about 7 years ago. There may be better ways to do that in mysqli, I just copied the example on the PHP documentation site. With PDO it would just be this (which is so much more elegant):

```
$stmt = $PDO->prepare('SELECT *  FROM employees where username = :username');
$stmt->execute([':username' => $username]);

$num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
$pass = $stmt->fetchColumn(0);
```

And the above assumes you are using PHP's built in password functions, which you should.

So to create a password use `password_hash`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

And to check it use `password_verfy`.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

**SQL Injection**

In your original code we could turn you query into this,

```
  "SELECT *  FROM employees where username = ".$_POST['username']." AND password = ".$_POST[password]"
```

This is equivalent to what you have. Without preparing it someone can enter `" OR 1=1` in the password field. There are only 2 styles of quotes and it wouldn't take much to figure it out.  You can also encode the quotes in some instances, so simply checking for quotes wont due. What this would do is make your query:

```
 SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "admin" AND password = "" OR 1=1
```

Now because `1` is always equal to one `1` and this is `password OR 1` then it effectively bypasses the password.  You should only pull the password from the DB and then check it in PHP.  That would prevent all of this (even with the sql issues) because as an attacker I would still need the password to pass that check. For example.

```
 SELECT password FROM employees where username = "" OR 1=1
 ...
 //even with a hacked row from the DB I still don't have $_POST['password']
 if($_POST['password'] == $row['password'])
```

**A few other Attacks**

For the username it's almost the same `" OR 1=1 --`. The `--` is the start of a line comment in SQL. And, because you are not checking the number of returned results it would also log me in as probably the first user found.

```
SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "" OR 1=1 -- AND password = "
```

However if even if you did (check the number of results) all I would need to add is LIMIT 1 `" OR 1=1 LIMIT 1 --` to it.  I would probably do it this way anyway, if I was a hacker.

```
SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "" OR 1=1 LIMIT 1 -- AND password = "
```

Then to boot I could iterate thought all your users by using an offset.

```
SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "" OR 1=1 LIMIT 0, 1 -- AND password = "
SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "" OR 1=1 LIMIT 1, 1 -- AND password = "
SELECT *  FROM employees where username = "" OR 1=1 LIMIT 2, 1 -- AND password = "
etc.
```

And then steal all their stuff, or pick one with administrative rights your site etc.

**Problem with not encrypting passwords**

One of the biggest problems (outside of the obvious ones) is that users are lazy and they tend to use the same passwords.  So once I compromised and admin account or even if you show the old password when a user goes to change it. Whatever way I get it...  I could try that password against their email, also in their account. And once I find the poor sucker that has the same email password, I could find any sites they use. Then use that common password (preferred as they wont even know) or now that I own their email account I can just reset the password if I need to, to gain access to things like their online banking accounts etc..

So as you can see this is not something we can allow to happen.

Even when just learning, we should try to learn to do it the proper way, or at least in a way that offers some minimal security.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! I figured that one out just a bit ago. I decided to get rid of my SignIn() function entirely, as it seems to not be needed in this case. Made my variables behave a bit nicer.

Comment: Me personally I would write a User class, but I only like OOP